# Remove PDF passwords with PowerShell (or CMD)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, pdf, passwords

This is an exemplary *duplicate* of [this Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930863/removing-bulk-pdf-password).

I have a number of PDF files that have been sent to me *encrypted* with a password, which happens to be the same for all PDFs for simplicity. I have no reason to keep the password when I store those files in my permanent archives, nor to type it every time I open those files.

I could use the linked Q&A to build a Docker-based solution to strip the password from the pdf files, **or** I could ask here if the same is possible with Windows 10.

I have access to `choco` if I need some packages.

Comment: `qpdf` has a [Windows executable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/qpdf/). You would just need to write the batch equivalent of the bash script in the linked answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I did it.

Step one: use `qpdf`.

As a choco user

```
choco install qpdf
```

Secondly, use the following PowerShell one-liner (I couldn't parallelize it because PS gave me an error). Takes a few seconds per file

```
$password = [THE_PASSWORD]
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { qpdf --decrypt --replace-input --password=$password $_.Name}
```

I was **extremely** confident running the script wild into production because I had a strong backup, and I had to restore it a couple of times.

Everyone around has suggested to **make a backup** before running live.

`qpdf` won't do anything if the file is not encrypted.

I will amend the question accordingly, **but the script assumes the password *is the same for all files***

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with [the script](https://superuser.com/a/1506875/399707) but ran this instead from a command prompt in Windows 10 (`CMD.EXE`):

```
FOR %G IN (*.pdf) DO qpdf --decrypt --password=mypassword "%G" --replace-input
```

(Obviously, replace `mypassword` with the actual password)

The `--replace-input` avoids the need to specify output filenames, and the use of [the `FOR` command](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) simply cycles through an entire folder of PDFs and removes the encryption.

Comment: Hint: Use `%%G` if you use this line in a batch file.